# дата отправки (--/:/ ) 7 февраля

Tags: пунктуация

*Тема спора:* нужны ли тире или двоеточие во фразе "Ориентировочная дата отправки указанного груза 7—9 февраля 2016 года". Или можно без знаков вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным: Двадцать лет — хорошая вещь (Сим.); Расставанья и встречи — две главные части, из которых когда-нибудь сложится счастье (Долм.); Трижды пять — пятнадцать; Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.

> Примечание. В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: Грузоподъёмность ***крана 2,5 тонны,*** вылет стрелы 5 метров; Температура плавления ***золота 1063о С.***

См.: [Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)

Comment: Вы опять не то правило привели. Здесь нет двух главных членов, чем-то там выраженных. Грамматику посмотрите. Предложение односоставное. У Розенталя в примерах тире можно замерить глаголом "есть", "составляет"  и т.д. Здесь этого нет. И почитайте уже, наконец, все случаи, когда ставится тире. Их в русском более одного. Есть даже такое понятие как интонационное тире. А то опять в лужу сядете.

Comment: @behemothus, он как раз именно то правило привёл, здесь вопрос в том, ставить ли тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым или нет.

Comment: Да? А что здесь подлежащее и что именное сказуемое, не раскроете страшную тайну?

Comment: Чтобы вам проще было. "Дата отгрузки - начало февраля".  Тире есть, числительного нету. А случай тот же, что и в исходном вопросе. Дата - это вообще очень спорное "числительное". А если и числительное, то порядковое, таких примеров у Розенталя нет.  Не надо идти на поводу у Сержа.

Comment: @behemothus, Серж ошибся по поводу числительного, но Вы ошиблись по поводу односоставности.

Comment: *Вы ошиблись по поводу односоставности.* - готов обсудить. Но это вопрос второстепенный, началось-то с утверждения, что Серж привел "то" правило. Признаете что правило **не то**? Если да, то можем продолжить конструктивно.

Comment: @behemothus, правило не то, но глава Розенталя та. Обсуждать не хочу, потому что мне не нравится формулировка "не раскроете страшную тайну".

Comment: *правило не то*  - что и требовалось доказать. А одолжений мне не надо делать, особенно тех, которых я не просил. Конкретную фразу  вы как разбираете? Что у вас подлежащее, что сказуемое. Без мыслей по древу.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, можно и так оставить, без знаков. Возможно и тире, но не двоеточие.

Comment: мой вариант был без знаков. Вариант оппонента, что обязательно должен быть какой-то знак (тире, двоеточие). Мне было рекомендовано найти правило, которое разрешает НЕ использовать в этой фразе знаки! )

Comment: Понятно.) Конкретной ссылки не могу дать, к сожалению. Но behemothus, видите, тоже подтвердил, что можно и без знака.

Comment: *Мне было рекомендовано найти правило, которое разрешает НЕ использовать...* - постановка вопроса некорректная. Свод правил пунктуации строится на другом принципе. Обязательный знак ставится тогда и только тогда, когда без него нельзя явно - и именно так написано в правилах. Если не написано иное, то знак не нужен (или, как минимум, не обязателен).

Comment: Другими словами, это Вы имеете полное право потребовать правило, по которому знак обязателен, а вот насчет отсутствия правила о необязательности - это не аргумент.

Comment: Именно вашим путем я и шел, но оппонент находится в кресле генерального директора, поэтому досталось искать правило мне. )))

Comment: Ну тогда я вам могу только посочувствовать. Если Гендиректор диктует правила пунктуации всему языку.)))

Comment: Вам самому не смешно?! Это вы занимаетесь отсебятиной, что видно из многочисленных споров, где вы опровергаете авторитеты. Везде ошибка - у вас все правильно! Может, уже хватит, везде свое мнение навязывать. И, в отличии от вас, я почти всегда ссылаюсь на авторитетные источники!

Comment: Нет, не смешно. А вы меня развеселить пытаетесь? По поводу Ваших ссылок. Я уже говорил, что ссылаться вы можете хоть на господа Бога. Но если тескт по Вашей ссылке не соответствует Вашей  трактовке, то простите, грош цена всем вашим нагугленным ссылкам.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше тире. Чисто зрительно. Двоеточие тут не совсем по правилам получается, мотивации нет достаточной. Хотя часто используют, в бланках, например. Тире же знак почти вольный, можно ставить почти везде, где хочется.

Без знака тоже возможно, но не так наглядно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, а не "можно" без знаков.

Объясните Вашему оппоненту, что присутствие знаков регулируется правилами, отсутствие же - нет. (То самое "нет", на которое нет суда.)

Постановка двоеточия или тире будет дизайнерским ходом, как **Ъ** у "Коммерсанта". Что, согласитесь, к языку отношения не имеет.

Когда никак не обнаруживается правило, а очень хочется, ориентируются на прецедент с близкой конструкцией, прецедент-синоним:

> Время прибытия группы 17:39.

Comment: Т.е.  "Время прибытия группы 17:39" - т.е. Вы тоже не читаете тго, что пишут другие? А как насчет правила замены отсутвующего глагола связки на тире? Даже Серж его знает. Это я про Ваш прецедент. Вы его совершенно напрасно тире лишили. А как насчет правила интонационного тире?